# Filemaker Loose Query

Tags: filemaker

In SQL based db's, I'm able to perform a "loose" query by appending e.g. %taxi% and consiquently get an entry containing taxi in it (e.g. w10taxi or taxiAirport or parcelTaxi).

How do I do this in FMP? (I've tried ~taxi but this appears not to work)

I'd appreciate any help. thanks in advance
Giles

Answer (score 2):

Use `*taxi`. Also check [help](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/find_sort.5.2.html#1027519), there's many other wildcards. The `~` you used is specific to Japanese language.